# SWT Link Text with >

Tags: hyperlink, swt

I am trying to create a SWT Link with the text so it looks like the following

<this is the link>

where the text **this is the link** is the actual link and the angle brackets are not part of the link.

I can get close with the following code:

```
link.setText("<a><this is the link></a>");
```

However, I want just the text to be the link, and not include the < and >.  I thought I could do it simply by doing:

```
link.setText("<<a>this is the link</a>>");
```

But when I do that - I lose the ending >.  Can anyone think of how to get the > back (without it being part of the link?

Comment: Hmm, I try your sample link.setText("<<a>this is the link</a>>"); and I get what I think you are going for.  I see < followed by the link followed by >.

Comment: Yeah - Now I need to figure out what I am doing in my project that is causing a difference.  If I do it in a simple project (the SWT snippet) it works fine.  When I add the same code to my file, it doesnt...

Comment: Provide more context to your code and maybe someone else can spot the issue.

Comment: Tried this in my own SWT based project out of curiosity and I get <link text. Omitting the first < gets me link text>. Extra spaces don't help. Using SWT 3.550.

Comment: And it looks like any number of trailing >'s gets converted to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SWT are you testing with?  When I run the first SWT [sample snippet](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#link) for Link, but replace the text with your sample

```
link.setText("<<a>this is the link</a>>");
```

then I see what I believe you want to see.  This is with SWT 3.3.2.

Comment: Tried the following code - but it resulted in 'lt;this is the linkgt;'

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
link.setText("<<a>this is the link</a>> >");
```